# Running JUnit from command prompt: classpath confusion

Tags: junit, classpath

I'm having trouble getting from a working JUnit command line invocation to something only slightly more complicated. At the outset, 'hw' is a class with no package specified. The following command is successfully executed from the dir in which hw.class lives:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/hamcrest-core.jar:/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.junit4_4.5.0.v20090824/junit.jar:./ org.junit.runner.JUnitCore hw
```

I now specify a package 'p' for hw, move hw.java into subdir 'p', and recompile. How can I modify the above command to have the class successfully tested? I've have thought that

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/hamcrest-core.jar:/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.junit4_4.5.0.v20090824/junit.jar:p org.junit.runner.JUnitCore p/hw
```

would work from the 'superdir' of p, but it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your command:

- The classpath must include the directory that is at the root of the package hierarchy, i.e. not `p` but the directory containing `p`.
- The argument to JUnitCore is the fully qualified name of the class, i.e. `p.hw` not `p/hw`

Answer (score 0):

The classes are missed at the time of execution of test in classpath of the project
s
Solution : add in your pom
         
             commons-discovery
             commons-discovery
             0.5
             test